# Run compiled C code from Python in Mac

Tags: python, c, macos, python-2.7, osx-yosemite

I'm very new to OS X, as I just started learning it today out of necessity, so maybe this is a simple question.

I'm testing a python wrapper script that encompasses several C files in Mac. I call scripts using `subprocess.check_call()`, with a sample parameter of `'cScript ' + inputFile + ' ' + outputFile`. The scripts were all compiled using gcc in windows, and thus are .exe files.

That's the problem. When I run the python script I get "OSError: no such file or directory" returned from check_call. I have the OS X command line dev tools including gcc installed, and I even changed the permissions on the C scripts using chmod +x. Nothing worked, however, and I get the same "no such file" error. I'm sure there's a workaround for this, and I'd love any help, but as a new, incompetent Mac user I don't understand why this is even an issue in the first place.

Thanks in advance!

Note: I have extensively tested all of the scripts, including the wrapper script, in Windows using MingW and they all work fine.

Comment: If they're .exe they're no longer C, they're fully-compiled native Windows executables. You'll have to get the source code and recompile them into OS X executables.

Comment: Note, too, that OS X binary executables do not conventionally carry an ".EXE" extension, unlike Windows executables.  This is perhaps the *direct* reason for the "no such file or directory" error in particular, instead of a different error complaining about the executable format.

Comment: Thank you! Your explanations helped a lot. OS X compatibility added :)